# SwiftUI value of type [x] has no member [y], but the struct has the member

Tags: swiftui

I'm getting an error that **Value type of `screen` has no member `elements`**, but looking at my struct I can see it there.  Is there a limit in how far my `foreach` can drill down to?

Here's where I'm getting the error

```
ForEach(remedydata?.remedy.content.screens.elements ?? []) { remedy in
```

If I remove `elements` I don't have any issues

My state is set as

```
@State var remedydata: Welcome? = nil
```

My struct looks like the below

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let remedy: Remedy
}

// MARK: - Remedy
struct Remedy: Codable {
    let id, tenantID: String
    let version: Int
    let title, remedyClientID, createdAt, remedyDescription: String
    let enabled: Bool
    let trigger: Trigger
    let requiredHostCapabilities: [RequiredHostCapability]
    let localizedStrings: [LocalizedString]
    let content: Content
    let actor: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case tenantID = "tenantId"
        case version, title
        case remedyClientID = "remedyClientId"
        case createdAt
        case remedyDescription = "description"
        case enabled, trigger, requiredHostCapabilities, localizedStrings, content, actor
    }
}

// MARK: - Content
struct Content: Codable {
    let serializationVersion: Int
    let screens: [Screen]
}

// MARK: - Screen
struct Screen: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let elements: [Element]
}

// MARK: - Element
struct Element: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let tag: Tag
    let text: String
    let action: Action?
```

Comment: You can't do `remedydata?.remedy.content.screens.elements` since `remedydata?.remedy.content.screens` is an Array. Did you instead want to use `remedydata?.remedy.content.screens` and then you can get `elements` within the `ForEach`?

Comment: That makes sense.  I am trying to get into `elements`.  Would I then to explicitly call out which item from the array I want?

Comment: I don't know what you want. Do you want to display every `element` of a certain `screen` on different rows? Or do you want to display some (or every) `element` from each `screen` on different rows? If you just want access to `elements` inside the `ForEach`, use `ForEach(remedydata?.remedy.content.screens ?? []) { screen in` with `screen.elements`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm trying to get to `text` within `Element`

Comment: But you have multiple `Element` inside multiple `Screen`. I'm not sure which way round you want this

Comment: Sorry about this.  I'm trying to create a list of the `elements in `Screen`, but I just need the first one.  I don't know if I'm explaining myself correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224754/discussion-between-robert-and-george-e).

Comment: If you need the first one, you can use this: `remedydata?.remedy.content.screens.first?.elements` (note the additional `first` part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do `remedydata?.remedy.content.screens.elements` since `remedydata?.remedy.content.screens` is an Array. In the question, you have multiple `Element` inside multiple `Screen`, which means you have two options:

- Display each `Element` for a specific `Screen`.
- Display a specific `Element` for each `Screen`.

To "Display each `Element` for a specific `Screen`":

```
ForEach(remedydata?.remedy.content.screens.first?.elements ?? []) { element in
    Text(element.text)
}
```

To "Display a specific `Element` for each `Screen`":

```
ForEach(remedydata?.remedy.content.screens ?? []) { screen in
    Text(screen.elements.first?.text ?? "")
}
```